# Meaning of gradient in multivariable case

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I'm going through some solutions to past questions and in one solution it is written:

$$\nabla f(x(s,t),t)$$

What would this mean expanded out? I would've thought it meant, here $x$ is representing the position, so x would have $x,y,z$ components. Would the $s$ be included in the expanded expression?

EDIT: the solution states $\frac{df}{ds}=\frac{dx}{ds}\cdot\nabla f$, I was just abit confused as to how they arrived at this expression, I know theyve applied the chain rule but just wanted an explanation.

Comment: The chain rule?

Comment: I think some more context would be helpful. As written, this is just the gradient of $f$ evaluated at the point $(x(s,t),t)$.